# JQuery selector not working when selecting an HTML class holding a Youtube embed

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I am trying to use a JQuery selector to select the title of a YouTube video. The HTML is as follows:

```
  <div class="ytp-title-text">
        <a class="ytp-title-link yt-uix-sessionlink" 
        tabindex="13" 
        target="_blank" 
        data-sessionlink="feature=player-title" 
        href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKVXR7tIa2k">More To Play For</a>
</div>
```

My code is

```
$('.ytp-title-link.yt-uix-sessionlink').text('a');
```

My result is "".

I expect the outcome to be: `'More to Play'`

I am simply writing this code in the console of the latest Chrome browser in the hope it prints out 'More to Play'. However, it is not working. The same approach to other classes works with the web page I am working with.

But, I'm having problems with this YouTube snippet. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$('.ytp-title-link.yt-uix-sessionlink').text('a');` Missed `.` with `yt-uix-sessionlink`, _Its typo question hence voted to close the question_

Comment: @Satpal - is it a typo? or lack of knowledge?

Comment: @JaromandaX, You are open for interpretation. If you feel its _lack of knowledge_ go ahead answer it, I will be first one to upvote and you should not have deleted your answer

Comment: it's been answered already

Comment: nope - @dwreck08 beat me to it - I saw his answer come up just as I was about to hit post :p

Comment: @Satpal This was a typo in my question. I have fixed this. The problem remains. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have a space instead of a class selctor. Should be:

`$('.ytp-title-link.yt-uix-sessionlink').text('a');`

This is just going to change the anchor to have text of "a".  If you want to grab (not change) the text, you just want:

`$('.ytp-title-link.yt-uix-sessionlink').text();`

**Example here:**
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dnj8juvr/)

Comment: Thanks @dwreck08. I have addressed the typo in the question. The problem remains. You made a great suggestion though by removing 'a'.

Comment: Need to see what you are trying to do with it and how.

Comment: Thanks @dwreck08. I have updated my question. I am pasting this code into the Chrome browser console currently as a test. Once I get it to work, I will the use the code for Google Tag Manager.

Comment: So it does... It might be something to do with the browser console then. Thanks